# Android SQLITE Order by not working correctly A and Ã

Tags: android, string, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a query that return a list of people's name and I have it order by last name.

The person with a last name start Ã is listed all the way at the end after the person with a last name start with Z

Question 1: Is Ã supposed to be after the A, or part of the A, or It should be sitting after Z

Question 2: If it is part of A how can I control it with the Query order by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the [collation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation) of your column. The sqlite C API allows you to define your own collation using [`sqlite3_create_collation()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html), but that does not seem to be exposed through Android's Java-side API.

However, the [`SQLiteDatabase` class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) mentions that Android automatically adds a few extra collations. One of those is `LOCALIZED`. This *may* give you a sorting where A and Ã are considered the same (or at least adjacent) -- however, the results will vary by the user's chosen locale, so it could be inconvenient if you need ordering to be the same for all users.

Answer (score -1):

Since Android framework is based on Java programming language, characters are encoded by default with UTF-8.

If you take a look into any [unicode character table](http://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character) you'll notice that 
Ã is number 00C3 in that list and Z is 005A (00C3 > 005A / Ã > Z).

So in order to ask your **Question 1**: Ã is supposed to be after Z